# Xamarin.iOS designer constraints

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, xamarin-studio

I am creating app with MvvCross for iOS with Xamarin studio on the mac.

When I set all sizes and constraints for the table view, after rebuild it gets broken(resizes to initial size) and orange but when I ran it on the device, it shows like it should be, any ideas?

Comment: It is very likely that you hit a rendering issue. If possible, open a bug to Xamarin's bug tracker and wait for them to fix.

Comment: Ok, will try that, thanks

Comment: Can you show us your code / constraints / editor ? You're probably in a specific size where it "looks" fine on your device because it resized to the same size as your device. While on simulator, you might have a bigger screen and therefore the resizing is visible

Comment: It wasn't a bug, I was using constraints in wrong way.